# To calculate generating function

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

If $a_{n}$ = $\frac {1}{(n-1)(n+1)}$ for $n\ge2$

What are we supposed to do with $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$?

How can I find the generating function without using $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$?

Comment: Are you missing an $a_{n-1}$?

Comment: No, this is the only thing given

Comment: Then $a_0$ and $a_1$ can either be arbitrary, or not defined.

Comment: you have what people call a 'closed form expression', i.e. $a_n$ does not depend on $a_{n-k}$.

Comment: So, what should I do with it? Don't we need $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$ to calculate the generating function?

Comment: Think to partial fraction decomposition, then begin by finding the generating function for the $1/(n-1)$...

Comment: I know the process by partial fraction but my main concern is how to get $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $a_0$ and $a_1$ are not specified, one usually leaves them out of the generating function, essentially assuming they are $0$.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{x^k}{(k-1)(k+1)}
&=\frac12\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1{k+1}\right)x^k\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^{k+1}}{k}-\frac12\sum_{k=3}^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{k}\\
&=\frac12\left(x-\frac1x\right)\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k}+\frac12\left(1+\frac x2\right)\\
&=\frac{1-x^2}{2x}\log(1-x)+\frac{2+x}4
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Your $\dfrac{2+x}{4}$ is what leads to $a_0=a_1=0$, and any other $b+cx$ there could be used to produce other arbitrary values for $a_0$ and $a_1$

Comment: @Henry: yes, as I said above, we leave out the terms for $k=0$ and $k=1$ from the generating function, which essentially sets them to be $0$. Unless $a_0$ or $a_1$ are defined, it does not make sense to include the terms referencing them, so they are usually left out of the generating function.  $\frac{2+x}4$ is there only to get rid of the terms with $x^0$ and $x^1$.